# Not understanding Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
t = [[3-i for i in range(3)]for j in range(3)]
s = 0
for i in range(3):
   s += t[i][i]
print(s)
```

Eventually the result should be 6.Can please someone explain me the whole proccess and why is everything happening,because I can not get it on my own.
Thank you all and look forward to get so helpful information.

As far as what i could understand it should go like this :

1. interraction i = 3-0 = 0 and j = 0
2. interraction i = 3-1 = 2 and j = 1
3. interraction i = 3-2 = 1 and j = 2

but the second part i cant understand at all and would not know what to do

Comment: Nope : `3-0 => 3`. Then you sum 1+2+3

Comment: Print each variable at every step of the program.  This will explain everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The following `[3 - i for i in range(3)]` creates the list `[3, 2, 1]` because of `[3-0, 3-1, 3-2]`
2. You repeat this operation 3 times because you have **nested list comprhensions** (because of `j`, note `j` value **is not used**), you end up with, a list containing 3 identicals lists of `[3,2,1]`

   ```
   # inline display
   [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

   # two dimension display
   [[3, 2, 1], 
    [3, 2, 1], 
    [3, 2, 1]]
   ```
3. Then you sum the values of positions `0,0`, `1,1` and `2,2`
4. Which means the values with parenthesis in the following piece of code

   ```
   [[ (3),  2 ,  1  ], 
    [  3 , (2),  1  ], 
    [  3 ,  2 , (1) ]]
   ```
5. And `3 + 2 + 1 == 6`

---

The following code does the same as `[[3-i for i in range(3)]for j in range(3)]` but some prints to help

```
t = []
# repeat 3 times
for ite in range(3):
    temp = []
    for i in range(3):
        temp.append(3 - i)
    print("Iteration", ite, "ADD", temp, "to 't'")
    t.append(temp)
```

Comment: I just have one more question.If a had for example in the second part of program in range(2), would it then be just sum of (0,0) and (1,1,) which gives 5?

Comment: @MarkoKostic why don't you just try ? Yes.